# After today's boot, XMG laptop screen only shows noise

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, screen

This is [my laptop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n65U0.jpg) after login.
I have a XMG core 15 with a GTX 1650 Ti.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel `5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30`.
My monitors via HDMI and DP are working fine.
I already tried purging the nvidia drivers and reinstalling different versions.

I tried using `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but it just installed nvidia-drivers-470.

- nvidia-driver-460: Monitors work, laptop screen doesn't
- nvidia-driver-470: Monitors not recognized, laptop screen doesn't work.
- nvidia-driver-495: See nvidia-driver-460.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: can you please send your vbios file? i am searching for this for almost two months.

Comment: By now I don't have the Laptop anymore. I actually got it fixed by disabling the Nvidia Driver and then slowly going through the Nvidia Version until i found one that works.

Comment: Also one of the next updates after that fixed it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. After kernel upgrade to 5.13.0-27 the notebook display flickers. I'm using a XMG Core 17 with GTX 1650 TI.
I've tried all combinations of lightdm/gdm3 and Nvidia 460.91.03 and 470.86. Always the same behavior.
When I boot kernel 5.11.0-46 everything works fine.

These are the upgraded packages of today...at least one of them should be responsible for that behavior :

Install: linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic
), linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-27:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23, 5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-94.106, 5.4.0-96.109), ruby2.7:amd64 (2.7.0-5ubuntu1.5, 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.6), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.
4.2~20.04.1, 27.5~20.04.1), gdb:amd64 (9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04, 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23, 5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23, 5.13.0.27.2
9~20.04.13), libruby2.7:amd64 (2.7.0-5ubuntu1.5, 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.6), gdbserver:amd64 (9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04, 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.24, 1.187.25)

Answer (score 0):

I believe elhe and me are using nearly the same notebook from bestware.com. at least my notebook does not have this bios option. it was mentioned that this bevahior is only driven by optimus. externel display are always driven by the nvidia dgpu while the notebook display can be driven by amd igpu or nvidia dgpu.

meanwhile i found 2 links...looks like an issue with amd igpu and kernel 5.14 obviously contains a fix :
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/rwnn7n/amd_ryzen_desktop_users_hold_off_with_513023/
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958494

Comment: Yes I think we have almost the same laptop (mine from a german seller) with a ryzen cpu. So it looks like it will be fixed in 5.14